# Creating a SharePoint signed URL

Tags: sharepoint-server, javascript, authentication, nodejs

The below is the SharePoint URL to access the required document:

```
https://companyName.sharepoint.com/_api/web/GetFileByRelativeUrl(%27/companyName%20ABC/contact/fileName.jpg%27)/$value
```

But pasting the link in the browser does not open the document.

How to create a signed URL to assist the front end directly open the signed URL in the browser.

I am using NodeJs in the back end. Need to have a NodeJs code.